# How to conditionally reverse the order of a stream where I'm using comparators to sort initially?

Tags: java, java-stream

I have code as such, which selects and chains comparators:

```
class InputObject {  String inputName;  String ascending; }

Map<String, Comparator> comparatorsMap = .... // Used to dynamically pull comparators for use

List<InputObject> input = Arrays.asList(new InputObject("hello", true), new InputObject("goodbye", false));

Comparator<OutputObject> comparator = input.stream()
        .map(comparatorsMap::get)
        .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
        .orElse((a, b) -> 0);

List<OutputObject> sorted = dataCollection.stream().sorted( comparator ).collect( Collectors.toList() );
```

I'd like to use the `ascending` field from InputObject as a conditional to determine if it should reverse the collection, but I'm not sure how to achieve that. Note that each input object has its own `ascending` field, so these would have to be intermediate actions.

So example:

Unsorted (input stream is `[ {"byName", false}, {"byID", true} ]` ):

```
OutputObject=("Mike", 5)
OutputObject=("Bob", 4)
OutputObject=("Mike", 1)
```

After first sort (on name):

```
OutputObject=("Bob", 4)
OutputObject=("Mike", 5)
OutputObject=("Mike", 1)
```

Then reverse (since `ascending == false`)

```
OutputObject=("Mike", 5)
OutputObject=("Mike", 1)
OutputObject=("Bob", 4)
```

Then after applying the second sort (by ID if tie, and `ascending == true`)

```
OutputObject=("Mike", 1)
OutputObject=("Mike", 5)
OutputObject=("Bob", 4)
```

I thought about potentially saving a boolean field within the map lambda and leveraging that in a different lambda, but I'm not sure how you can apply the action of reversing the stream / collection conditionally.

Comment: "if it should reverse the collection post-sorting or not" I don't understand what this means. Reversing isn't done after sorting, it's done on every comparison. Moreover, the entire chain of comparisons is applied on every comparison; it's not a case of applying "first", "second".

Comment: Note that `comparatorsMap::get` wouldn't work, because the input parameter to the `map` is `InputObject`, not `String`. You'd need `in -> comparatorsMap.get(in.inputName)`, or similar.

Comment: Your `reduce` operation makes very little sense; I don't think it's doing what you want, but I have no idea what you really want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for something like this:

```
Comparator<OutputObject> comparator = input.stream()
        .map(in -> {
          Comparator<OutputObject> c = comparatorsMap.get(in.inputName);
          return in.ascending ? c : c.reversed();
        })
        .reduce(Comparator::thenComparing)
        .orElse((a, b) -> 0);
```

This conditionally reverses the comparator from `comparatorsMap`, based on the `ascending` flag.

> I thought about potentially saving a boolean field within the map lambda and leveraging that in a different lambda

You could do it like this:

```
input.stream()
    .map(in -> new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(comparatorsMap.get(in.inputName), in.ascending))
    .map(e -> e.getValue() ? e.getKey() : e.getKey().reversed())
    ...
```

but I think that's far less easy to understand.